# SQ writing queries

Tags: sql

In SQL how do I display only the columns `LastName, FirstName, BusinessEntityID` (show the output in that order) all rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty simple:

```
Select LastName, FirstName, BusinessEntittyID from table_name 
order by LastName, FirstName, BusinessEntittyID
```

Comment: Thank you for being kind I just started learning this.

Comment: Best wishes. You will surely enjoy the journey of learning. If you feel that my answer has helped you please mark as accepted by clicking the green check mark.